# Variation on Views exposed filter

Tags: views

I am working on a Drupal 7 site. One View on the site that lists hundreds of publications around a scientific theme has this great set of exposed filters in a bar at the top that allows researchers to search the publications. Unfortunately, the site owner and graphic artist went a little wild with another section, and designed this great set of filters that should bring up results in a View, but the filters aren't on a View page. Can the "exposed filters" for a View Page be placed on a different page altogether?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you expand?  What do you mean the filters aren't on a view page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make it a block. Assign it to a region on a particular page. When the user clicks the Apply button the view will be displayed.